# Connect to MySQL from Hive

Tags: mysql, hive

I want to connect my MySQL database to Hive so that I can access tables from MySQL server through Hive. I have searched the net and only found solutions for setting MySQL as a metastore database for Hive. But, did not find any methods for my problem. Can anyone please help me set this up? I am expecting something like [this](http://blog.rajithdelantha.com/2014/02/hive-mongodb.html) except for MySQL instead of MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using two ways. 
One is by importing the mysql table to hdfs and hive using sqoop. Direct hive import is possible through [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/). This will create the hive table corresponding to that of mysql in hadoop. Once you import the table to hive, then the new table will work as a hive table alone.

Another way is by using a serde to access mysql tables. I found one [hive-mysql](https://github.com/x-zhang/hive-mysql) serde in github. I haven't tested this serde. If you are good in java, you can write your own serde.

The example that you mentioned above is using a hive-mongodb SerDe.

Answer (score 0):

Hive 2.3.0+ provides ability to define external tables from your MySQL/Postgres/etc using [`JdbcStorageHandler`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JdbcStorageHandler):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student_jdbc
(
  name string,
  age int,
  gpa double
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "hive.sql.database.type" = "MYSQL",
    "hive.sql.jdbc.driver" = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "hive.sql.jdbc.url" = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample",
    "hive.sql.dbcp.username" = "hive",
    "hive.sql.dbcp.password" = "hive",
    "hive.sql.table" = "STUDENT"
    "hive.sql.dbcp.maxActive" = "1"
);
```

Also you can use `hive.sql.query` parameter instead of `hive.sql.table` to define more specific query like:

```
    "hive.sql.query" = "SELECT name, age, gpa FROM STUDENT"
```

See [Cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_query_sql_using_jdbcstoragehandler.html) also.